# How to completely remove activity from stack once finish is called over it?

Tags: android, memory-management

When I launch app my heap size increases to 10MB on first activity then when I go to next activity my heap size increases to 37 MB. On this second activity I am releasing some memory by `bitmap.recycle()` on button click so when clicked on particular button heap size decreases to 32MB. Now when I call finish to this second activity my memory size decreases to 16MB so giving a hint that it is not completely removed from stack since original memory size on first activity was 10MB.

Now when i go back to second activity it gives following crash that shows that bitmaps that I have released on button click are not being recreated. I am using same onCreate method on second activity everytime user enters that activity so it should have fetched bitmaps again from xml.

```
06-26 08:45:39.636: E/AndroidRuntime(6265): java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@41361ef0
```

What I am missing here? How to completely remove activity from stack once finish is called over it?

I have tried using `android:launchMode="singleTop"` and `android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"` on activity one and `android:launchMode="singleTop" android:noHistory="true"` on activity two.

any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Think we'll need some more code for your Activity's. I wouldn't use .recycle() I'd make sure your not losing a reference to your context (activity) somewhere

Comment: If you are going to reuse your 2nd activity, why are you recycling it then?

Comment: I want 2nd activity to be completely removed from stack once I call `finish()` over it and than recreate when i call it again. This is vital to the app.

Comment: @Blundell I dont understand what do you mean by losing reference to the activity. I have recycled bitmaps of some imageviews so when I recreate Intent of 2nd activity and call startActivity it gives error that I am using recycled bitmaps.

Comment: @AyazAlavi Here something like this: http://www.curious-creature.org/2008/12/18/avoid-memory-leaks-on-android/ is a 'losing a context'

Comment: Can you please tell me how you checked the memory size? because my app also behaving the same..

Answer (score 1):

In order to remove an application from the System's application stack, 
you can kill it's process. Maybe this helps?

```
/**************************************************************************************
*   Removes this application from the stack by killing it's process.
**************************************************************************************/
public static final void killProcess()
{
    //get current process id
    int processId = android.os.Process.myPid();

    //tell android to kill this process
    android.os.Process.killProcess( processId );
}
```

Comment: ...?  If i read this right, this kills the whole app.  Probably not the thing to do when you just want to reclaim the memory from one of its activities.

Comment: yes this will kill the process. I just want to remove memory of an activity once finish is called over it and recreate it when next called.

Answer (score 1):

Once finish is get called onDestroy will also get called and entire activity will be cleared but even though you want to try something manually, you can try stack clear or can call garbage collector. For your reference :

```
// For stack clear
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

// For calling GC
System.runFinalization();
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: which is this intent?